# Objective-C, NSMutableData not released

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmutabledata

My app sometimes reads data, uses it, then might need to read it again later. I noticed that if I read the data once it gets released, but if I happen to read it again it never gets released.

**Why is the data not released if read again?**

Code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self readData]; // read one
    NSLog(@"read1");
    sleep(1);
    [self readData2];
}

- (void)readData2 {
    [self readData]; // read two
    NSLog(@"read2");
}

- (void)readData {
    __block NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"test"]; // file is 125 MB
    NSUInteger size = [data length];
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            // do stuff
        }
        return;
}
@end
```

[image]

Comment: I've seen it asserted that `dataWIthContentsOfFile` effectively creates a "literal" with the value of the file data, and that persists, just like string literals and small NSNumber values.  I'm not sure how much I believe that, though.

Comment: Is there a reason for using the `__block` storage type in this case? How does it behave if you change that?

Comment: @HotLicks, Spot on and I do believe it. I'm not sure it's a literal, but the value is definitely retained using `dataWIthContentsOfFile` without `options`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error` with option:

**NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe**

> A hint indicating the file should be mapped into virtual memory, if
>   possible and safe.

Although the description of `dataWithContentsOfFile` does not indicate, not using the `options` will likely result in data being retained otherwise.

**dataWithContentsOfFile**

> This method is equivalent to dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:
>   with no options. If you need to know what was the reason for failure,
>   use dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:.